# Image Upload with diffrent name

Tags: php

```
<?php 
require_once 'location.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
    $screenshot_type = $_FILES['screenshot']['type'];
    $screenshot_size = $_FILES['screenshot']['size']; 

    if (!empty($screenshot)) {
          if ((($screenshot_type == 'image/gif') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/jpeg')      ||    ($screenshot_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/png'))
        && ($screenshot_size > 0) && ($screenshot_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE)) {
        if ($_FILES['screenshot']['error'] == 0) {
          // Move the file to the target upload folder
          $target = GW_UPLOADPATH .hash("md5", $screenshot);
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            // Connect to the database
           $dbc = mysqli_connect('locl', 'abc', '', 'xyz')
      or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

            // Write the data to the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO guitar VALUES ('$screenshot')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
           echo '<img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot . '" alt="Screen shot" />    
      </p>';
           echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to high scores</a></p>';

            // Clear the score data to clear the form
            $screenshot = "";

            mysqli_close($dbc);
          }
          else {
            echo '<p>Sorry, there was a problem uploading your screen shot image.</p>';
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        echo '<p>The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than 
' . (GW_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' KB in size.</p>';
      }

      // Try to delete the temporary screen shot image file
      @unlink($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name']);
    }
    else {
      echo '<p>Please enter all of the information to add your high score.</p>';
    }
  }



?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo  
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768" />
<label for="screenshot">Screen shot:</label

>
<input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This code uploads image. But if their is image with same name already exist then it overwrites it. Sometimes, the user uploads images with the same name.

How could i resolve this problem. Or any way to add random name before name of image.